# Bind to read-only DOM property in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm working on integrating PDF.JS with Aurelia, and I'm currently working on scroll binding behavior (to load pages and update values when the user scrolls through a document).

To accomplish this, I decided to bind to the `offsetTop` property of a `canvas` element. My markup looks like this:

```
<canvas repeat.for="page of numPages" offset-top.bind="offsetTop[page + 1]" id="${'pdfCanvas' + (page + 1)}"></canvas>
```

The problem is, when I try to run this, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'offsetTop' of object '#<HTMLCanvasElement>'.
```

My question is this - is there a way to bind to a property in "read-only mode"? I'd like to monitor the property for changes (so that I can drive the page changes based on the offset positioning) but I don't want to write to it. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we don't have a built-in way to say "I want to dirty check this element property" in a binding expression. It's on our [backlog](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/issues/33) though.

In the specific case you've described (scrollTop) we can do better than dirty checking because there's a DOM event associated with the property.

Locate the "scroll container" element (the one with `overflow: scroll`) and use the `ref` attribute to give it a name.  Then bind to it's `scroll` event using `trigger`. The trigger expression should assign the scroll container element's current `scrollTop` to the view-model. You may want to use the `throttle` binding behavior to avoid perf/chop issues that are associated with doing a lot of work in a scroll event.

```html
<div ref="myDiv" scroll.trigger="scrollTop = myDiv.scrollTop & throttle">

   ...

</div>
```

https://gist.run/?id=db47a4f26f48e17250f2812ad159ea28

Comment: Gotcha. I thought about this approach (and in the container, I do have a `scroll.trigger` but the problem is that I need the offsetTop property from the children inside of the scrollable container. Using this approach you descrived, I'd have to reference all of the container children in my viewmodel and do the math inside of the scroll handler (using scrollTop and the offset for each child), which I was hoping to avoid as it wouldn't scale well.